# Suggest CDN with Byte-Range requests support for streaming

Tags: cdn, video-streaming, cloud-storage

I'm trying to find high load solution for streaming server.
The idea came to me this morning. 
What about CDN or cloud storage with byte-range support. Basically flash player require only partial video-file transfer from remote server and keep-alive connection.

Does anyone know whether this is a reasonable idea and whether CDNs support it?

Comment: First instinct was that this is a shopping question, but after re-reading it I see it's on the fringe..

Comment: @AaronCopley it was, before I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDNs are generally pretty shady about what exact features they support.  You'll need to contact them directly and ask whether they'll do what you want, and then figure out which one fits your use-case and budget best.

It turns out that `byte-range` is a HTTP header for flash pseudo-streaming.  I've done some googling about, and found a few articles that suggest that CDNs supporting this are:
[Edgecast](http://www.edgecast.com/services/streaming/), [Limelight](http://dyn.limelightnetworks.com/limelightstream.htm) and [NetDNA](http://www.netdna.com/products/http-caching/) ([src](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/servers-and-streaming/20387/cloudfront-http-pseudostreaming-seeking-http-11-headers/))
 and [Bitgravity](http://www.bitgravity.com/products/bg_video_delivery.html), [CDNetworks](http://www.cdnetworks.com/solutions/media-acceleration/), ([src](http://flash.flowplayer.org/forum/5/98787))

Comment: Rackspace Cloud Files officially supports streaming: https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/frequently-asked-question/getting-started-with-cloud-files-streaming